# DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED on index contraint in postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql

I can add DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED using the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE user DROP CONSTRAINT unq_user_address, add CONSTRAINT unq_user_address UNIQUE(user_address) deferrable INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Now I have another column and I want to add DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED. 
The constraint is on index so I am getting error when I do so.

Here is the index constraint:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_account
  ON user 
  USING btree 
  (lower(account::text) COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

I modified it to say,

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_account
      ON user 
      USING btree 
      (lower(account::text) COLLATE pg_catalog."default") deferrable INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Also tried,

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_account
      ON user 
      USING btree 
      (lower(account::text) COLLATE pg_catalog."default") UNIQUE_CHECK_PARTIAL;
```

So don't know how to apply the same on index.

I see the following official doc:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/index-unique-checks.html

> UNIQUE_CHECK_PARTIAL indicates that the unique constraint is
>   deferrable. PostgreSQL will use this mode to insert each row's index
>   entry. The access method must allow duplicate entries into the index,
>   and report any potential duplicates by returning FALSE from aminsert.
>   For each row for which FALSE is returned, a deferred recheck will be
>   scheduled.

And here:

> UNIQUE_CHECK_EXISTING indicates that this is a deferred recheck of a
>   row that was reported as a potential uniqueness violation. Although
>   this is implemented by calling aminsert, the access method must not
>   insert a new index entry in this case. The index entry is already
>   present. Rather, the access method must check to see if there is
>   another live index entry. If so, and if the target row is also still
>   live, report error.

Is it something I need to use and if yes then how?

Comment: "The constraint is on index so I am getting error when I do so." this part is not clear

Comment: did you mean ` alter table TABLE  add constraint NAME_CONST UNIQUE USING INDEX INDEX_NAME`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun - DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED doesn't work on index query for my case. For example: I can't do: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_account
  ON user 
  USING btree 
  (lower(account::text) COLLATE pg_catalog."default") deferrable INITIALLY DEFERRED;`

Comment: it sounds confusing. I thought it was a check constraint that can behave differently in transaction. I did not know you can influence unique index this way.

Comment: after reading Craig's answer, my offer to `ADD CONSTRAINT ... USING INDEX...` instead looses scene - no function on column alowed

Comment: @VaoTsun - So I think as Craig suggested, we need to drop the index and accept the loss of uniqueness on it or else you need to make the constraint instead of index or else leave it as an immediate constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot define an index as deferrable. Deferrable is an attribute of constraints, not indexes.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    test_col integer not null
);

ALTER TABLE test_table
ADD constraint test_col_unique unique (test_col) deferrable initially deferred;
```

However, you cannot use arbitrary expressions for unique constraints, only direct column references:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table
ADD CONSTRAINT test_col_abs_unique UNIQUE (abs(test_col));
```

will report

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
```

because the parser only handles simple column references.

So you can't make this check deferrable.

Comment: So the question is - how to defer the unique index check? The only way is to simply drop this unique index check? I have multiple persist calls on the table within the same transaction and I want to defer it so that Postgres wouldn’t enforce them until the end of the transaction. Here is something on deferring the unique index: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/index-unique-checks.html. However, I didn't get on how to use it.

Comment: I tried to first create index with function on column and then `ADD CONSTRAINT ... USING INDEX...` and got `DETAIL:  Cannot create a primary key or unique constraint using such an index.` - this is what you meant by "direct column reference"? attribute value as is?

Comment: Exactly. You can't use any expression - a function, operator, etc - in the index definition if you want to make it deferrable. Only raw column name(s). PostgreSQL does not currently (as of 9.6) support deferrable unique constraints other than on simple columns. So the answer is *you can't*. For a unique constraint you can't correctly re-implement it as a constraint trigger either. You will need to drop the unique index and accept the loss of that constraint, or leave it as an immediate constraint.

Comment: I dropped the unique index on it. I created it as a unique constraint rather than as a unique index and now things are working fine. I kept your point in mind - "You cannot define an index as deferrable". There is no adverse effect on converting the unique index to unique constraint. I also searched on postgres documentation and didn't found any major issue doing so.

Comment: How? What `alter table` statement did you use to get an expression to be accepted?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use neither of `UNIQUE_CHECK_PARTIAL`, `UNIQUE_CHECK_EXISTING` in `CREATE INDEX ...` SQL query. As it said on the [Access Method Interface](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/index-unique-checks.html)  documentation page you quote,

> ...the aminsert function is passed a checkUnique parameter
>   having one of the following values: UNIQUE_CHECK_NO...,
>   UNIQUE_CHECK_YES..., UNIQUE_CHECK_PARTIAL..., UNIQUE_CHECK_EXISTING

So those are values for **checkUnique** parameter to be passed to **aminsert function** (which I assume is a part of Access Method Interface API or internals)

The rest is answered by Craig.

You can `alter table "user" add CONSTRAINT unq_user_address UNIQUE(account) deferrable INITIALLY DEFERRED;` losing the `lower(account)` condition:

**as a workaround you can** do this ugly thing - add column and trigger:

```
b=# create table "user" (account text, account_uq text);
CREATE TABLE
b=# create function tf() returns trigger as $$ begin NEW.account_uq = lower(NEW.account); return NEW; end;$$ language plpgsql;
ERROR:  function "tf" already exists with same argument types
b=# CREATE TRIGGER tg BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON "user" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tf();
CREATE TRIGGER
b=# alter table "user" add CONSTRAINT another_uq UNIQUE(account_uq) deferrable INITIALLY DEFERRED;
ALTER TABLE
b=# insert into "user" (account) select 'b';
INSERT 0 1
b=# begin;
BEGIN
b=# insert into "user" (account) select 'B';
INSERT 0 1
b=# select * from "user";
 account | account_uq
---------+------------
 b       | b
 B       | b
(2 rows)

b=# end;
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "another_uq"
DETAIL:  Key (account_uq)=(b) already exists.
```

Comment: I didn't found anything worse in loosing the `lower(account)`. I simply dropped the index and rather created the constraint and it worked fine.

Comment: cool. I thought having a unique on function(column) was a fundamental question :)